# VB.net Datagridview, bind combobox with different datasources

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, combobox, datasource

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to bind items with datasource in each row in each combobox in my datagridview. 
Basically, I have 3 columns, 1st and 2nd rows are texts while the third row is a combobox.
1st row is the  `question category` 
2nd row is the  `question` 
3rd row is the  `answer for each question`

the answer varies per question, that's why the answer is set as a combobox.

This is what I've got so far..

```
For Each question As CRM.Domain.Entities.CampaignDB.CampaignQuestion In questions
    'get question category
    questionCategoryStr = questionCategory.Find(Function(column) column.QuestionCategoryId = question.QuestionCategoryId)
    'filter the answers
    answerStr = answers.FindAll(Function(column) column.CampaignQuestionId = question.CampaignQuestionId)

     Dim dgvcc As New DataGridViewComboBoxCell
     With dgvcc
         .DataSource = answerStr
         .ValueMember = "CampaignAnswerId"
          .DisplayMember = "Answer"
     End With

     'this will only add rows with question category and the question, 
     dgvSurveyQuestions.Rows.Add(questionCategoryStr.CategoryName, question.Question)
     'however, if I do this
     dgvSurveyQuestions.Rows.Add(questionCategoryStr.CategoryName, question.Question, dgvcc)
     'it throws an error "Datagridview Default Error Dialog"
Next
```

[image: Sample image of the error]

Answer (score 0):

lol okay now I get it..

```
 dgvSurveyQuestions.Rows.Add(questionCategoryStr.CategoryName, question.Question)
 dgvSurveyQuestions.Item(2, rowIndex) = dgvcc
```

rowIndex is a counter that starts from zero and increments as the loop progresses.